# Derivatives API not returning Properties.db file

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have seen few times that the properties.db file is coming with the converted model when using the derivative APIs.
I also tried the extract node module and the zip file does not contain properties.db too.

is there any change in the api for retrieving that file?

regards,
Afshin

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no specific API dedicated to retrieve the property DB file.

You can get its path by looking up the [manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) after the model is completed extracted/translated and download it from there using the [GET :urn/manifest/:derivativeurn](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET/) endpoint:

```
 {
                    "guid": "...",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:<urn>/output/properties.db",
                    "role": "Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase",
                    "mime": "application/autodesk-db",
                    "status": "success"
                },
```

In case it's not generated let us know the URN by dropping a line to forge.help at autodesk.com so we can look into it.